# Could youhelp me out in android xml?

Tags: android, xml

[image: xml layout in android studio]

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/bintent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="132dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/balram1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Alarm"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp" />
```

`
[image: but it appears in actual device like this image]

so what should i do to appears it on actual device

Comment: Can you paste the full xml?

Comment: This attribute is used only for the editor. **tools: attributes are stripped from the code and are only for development purposes**.  As I see above, it will show absolutely the position of `Button`

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly impossible to tell what's going on without the full xml file. I assume that the parent layout is a RelativeLayout since you're using the centerInParent attribute but I'm not sure why you're using the absolute X and Y values. They won't even do anything since the "tools" namespace is only for the layout editor. It doesn't affect the app at all.

My best guess is that you have your parent layout's width and height set to "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent", because otherwise your Alarm button would be centered on the screen properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having here, is that you have used the `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX` and `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY` attribitues. Attributes starting with `tools` are only for the layout designer.

What you should do, if you want to center the buttons, is to use a relative layout as the parent element and inside of it you can put your buttons. So it should be something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like all other answers, I am also not sure which parent layout you are using but somewhere in my mind is Constraint Layout. If yes then use the below code :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bintent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/balram1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Alarm"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bintent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```